# WPF Binding a label with properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

On my WPF app page i have 2 bindings
1. for a list of items as an observable collection
2. just to show some values on a lable using binding

My class struct like this

```
 public DbVersionModel DbVersion { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<BookStore> StoreCollection
  { get { return thisApp.app_Stores; } }


public class DbVersionModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _LocalVersion { get; set; }
    private int _ServerVersion { get; set; }
    private int _ActiveStores { get; set; }
    private string _LastModifiedLocal { get; set; }
    private string _LastModifiedServer { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyChange(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    public int LocalVersion
    {
        get { return _LocalVersion; }
        set
        {
            _LocalVersion = value;
            NotifyChange(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LocalVersion"));
        }
    }

    public int ServerVersion
    {
        get { return _ServerVersion; }
        set
        {
            _ServerVersion = value;
            NotifyChange(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ServerVersion"));
        }
    }

    public int ActiveStores
    {
        get { return _ActiveStores; }
        set
        {
            _ActiveStores = value;
            NotifyChange(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ActiveStores"));
        }
    }

    public string LastModifiedLocal
    {
        get { return _LastModifiedLocal; }
        set
        {
            _LastModifiedLocal = value;
            NotifyChange(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastModifiedLocal"));
        }
    }

    public string LastModifiedServer
    {
        get { return _LastModifiedServer; }
        set
        {
            _LastModifiedServer = value;
            NotifyChange(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastModifiedServer"));
        }
    }
}   public ManagePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    setContext();
}
private void setContext()
{
     try
    {

       DbVersionModel db_version = new DbVersionModel();

        db_version.LastModifiedServer = //set with value;
        db_version.ServerVersion = //set with value;

        db_version.LocalVersion = //set with value;
        db_version.LastModifiedLocal = //set with value;

        db_version.ActiveStores = //set with value;
        this.DbVersion = db_version;

    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

xaml like this

```
<Page x:Class="App.ManagePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>

</Page.Resources>
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
   <Grid Margin="5 10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--//    -->
                        <Label Content="Active stores[Local]"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Source=DbVersion, Path=ActiveStores}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>

                        <Label Content="Current version [Local]"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Source=DbVersion, Path=LocalVersion}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ></Label>

                        <Label Content="Curretn Version [Server]"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Source=DbVersion, Path=ServerVersion}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ></Label>

                        <Label Content="Last modified  [Local]"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" ></Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Source=DbVersion, Path=LastModifiedLocal}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" ></Label>

                        <Label Content="Last  modified [Server]"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" ></Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Source=DbVersion, Path=LastModifiedServer}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" ></Label>

                        <StackPanel   Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button Name="btnSync" Content="Sync stores" Height="30" Click="btnSync_Click" Style="{StaticResource ActionButtons}"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Also have a  ItemsControl which is getting loaded like this and binding is working fine here

```
    <ItemsControl Name="StoreListView" ItemsSource="{Binding StoreCollection}" Margin="5" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"  >
```

But ObservableCollection list binding is fine , but the label bindings are not working. How i can solve this?

How can i set binding on label based on properties of a class

Answer (score 0):

I think WPF does not notice the change of the `DbVersion` property because you set it after calling `InitializeComponent()`. Either you implement it as a `DependencyProperty`, which automatically notices if it is changed (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428(v=vs.110).aspx), or you use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `ManagePage` class (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Or call `setContext();` before `InitializeComponent();` in `ManagePage` constructor.

Comment: I changed my model with InotifyProperty changd event still not showing

Comment: You also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `ManagePage` class. In your implementation only the `DbVersionModel` notifies if one of its properties changes. You have to make the `ManagePage` class notice if the `DbVersion` property changes.

Comment: Or use a `DependencyProperty` for `DbVersion` here